# Resque worker is failing the jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, resque

I have deployed a Rails app on Heroku and assigned 5 Resque workers from Heroku resources which are working fine. But it seems like there is 1 more worker is assigned from somewhere else and failing the jobs as it does not have latest code.
If you see in the below screenshot, I have 6 workers instead of 5
[image: If you see in the below screenshot, I have 6 workers instead of 5]

and here, this worker is failing the jobs and it's 6th one.
[image]

and If I go to Heroku rails console and see the workers list, I can see the below list
[image]

Here's my Procfile command for resque.

```
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=7 bundle exec rake QUEUE=priority,settings_queue,default environment resque:work
```

Please, Help me to understand that why it's happening and what can be the possible solution for this? Is there a way to remove the 6th worker(which is causing jobs failure) permanently? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I'd like to know how you specify count of workers.

Comment: Hey @k0uh0t, thanks for joining. I specify the count of workers from Heroku dashboard. And the count is just 5.

Comment: I see, you mean you are using add-ons? 
First of all, Why don't you restart workers?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have restarted all the dynos many times but it did not fix the issue. Could you please let me know any other possible way to restart workers?

Comment: I have unregistered this worker and it's not available in the workers list anymore. But it's heartbeat still exist in Redis and worker is still working somehow.